# How does elastic beanstalk runs nodejs application code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My application is running ok in localhost but when I submit it to deploy in other place like aws (or mcs) it does not recognize the path of files that the lib consign needs to load the routes.

This is what I expect to run:

```
> portal@1.0.0 start /home/code/tmp/portal
> NODE_ENV=development nodemon index.js

[nodemon] 1.11.0
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
consign v0.1.2 Initialized in app
+ ./controllers/homeController.js
+ ./routes/routes.js
Ok! Express is running...
```

The trace below is what is happening at aws, see that it does not recognize the homeController.js file:

```
> portal@1.0.0 start /var/app/current
> NODE_ENV=development nodemon index.js

[nodemon] 1.11.0[39m
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`[39m
[nodemon] watching: *.*[39m
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`[39m
consign v0.1.2 Initialized in app
+ ./current/
+ ./current/
/var/app/current/app/routes/routes.js:2
    app.get('/',         app.controllers.homeController.index.bind(app.controllers.homeController)); 
                            ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'homeController' of undefined
    at Function.module.exports (/var/app/current/app/routes/routes.js:2:33)
at Consign.into (/var/app/current/node_modules/consign/lib/consign.js:239:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/var/app/current/config/express.js:18:6)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (/var/app/current/index.js:1:80)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
[31m[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...[39m
```

Any idea why this environment is messing with this application path?
Or how aws runs this code?

Comment: .... clearly `app` is undefined in the file /var/app/current/app/routes/routes.js on line 2. begin your research there.

Comment: EBS spins up an EC2 server based on your settings. You should be able to configure it in such a way that you can ssh into the server and look into things from there.

Comment: though... it seems a bit odd that you'd be deploying a server and using nodemon as the way you start/run the server. isn't nodemon a development tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue happened because of [this](https://github.com/jarradseers/consign/issues/9) behavior of Consign lib. The path used by aws was treated wrong because it has the string 'app' (/var/current/app/).

I fixed it using the whole path (process.cwd() + '/app').